# Update to 7.39 and multiple textfield appears in default value

Tags: entities

Updated Drupal core to 7.39 and in field default value, two textfield appears, one empty and another with a value of "t".

Attached is the screenshot of the issue.

[image]

Comment: please have look at this link if your filed was autocomplete before: https://www.drupal.org/node/2558605.